# Bridging the divide between two PIMPL types

Tags: c++, pimpl-idiom

Perhaps I am trying to be too clever, but I think I cannot have been the first one to try this and come across this problem. And I am secretly hoping that one of you knows what to do or to link me to a similar question with some good answers.

I am trying to wrap a 3rd party pure C database API in C++ classes. To abstract the database API away at the application layer, I am putting all its types and functionality in a PIMPL layer.
These classes will also double up as RAII types.

```
  Application               │     Database API
                                                
 ┌─────────────────────┐    │    ┌─────────┐         
 │ DatabaseConnection  ├────────►│ Impl    │         
 ├─────────────────────┤    │    ├─────────┤         
 │                     │         │ db_t    │         
 └─────────────────────┘    │    └─────────┘         
                                                                           
 ┌─────────────────────┐    │    ┌─────────────────┐ 
 │ Schema              ├────────►│ Impl            │ 
 ├─────────────────────┤    │    ├─────────────────┤ 
 │                     │         │ db_tabledef_t   │ 
 └─────────────────────┘    │    └─────────────────┘
```

So to make it abundantly clear, `db_t` and `db_tabledef_t` are types from this database API.

The declaration of `Schema` will look something like this:

```cpp
class Schema
{
  class Impl;

  friend class DatabaseConnection; // useful here at all?

public:
  // ctors/dtor/others here

private:
  std::unique_ptr<Impl> p_;
};
```

The `DatabaseConnection` class and others will look very similar. Meaning that the declaration of all "inner" PIMPL types will be inside the .cpp files.
That's my understanding on how the PIMPL idiom is implemented in C++, and one that `std::unique_ptr` seems to support.

At some point I need to bring these two or more bits of information together to make use of the database API.
As an example: at the first hurdle I wish to call a function on the database API to create the table in the database using a free function `db_create_table()`. For this I need both parts `db_t` and `db_tabledef_t`.

Obvious first inclination is to create method `DatabaseConnection::createTable()` taking a `Schema` as its parameter. This could of course delegate to its PIMPL type, which makes sense.

But how can I access `Schema::Impl` from with a function in `DatabaseConnection` or its PIMPL type?

It looks to me like you cannot get away with this design and *not* expose some of the database API at the application layer.
Or in other words: one will need a "getter".

Or is there another - hopefully community endorsed - way that keeps the application layer interface clean from the C API types?

**Side note**
I am tagging this question as C++ because that is what I am using, but other languages may face similar issues. If you know of one, drop a comment and I shall add that tag so we may widen the scope for future searches.

Comment: What I would do is first create the whole impl layer in my library, then attach the "pimpl front ends" (for lack of a better word) to that.  You will still end up with something pimpl like to the outside world, and internally you can use all the types you like. Usually I call those layers the functional (or business logic) layer and the API layer. This even allows you to have an internal design that differs from the API layer if needed (e.g. the API layer can be simpler)

Comment: why is Schema a separate thing? I dont fully understand why that needs to be PIMPL'd as well?

Comment: @Raildex It's to abstract away the workings of the C API to this database, which is a rats nest of header dependencies. It keeps their .h files out of ours. Schema is an otherwise stateful class, but with the PIMPL it's contained behind the interface.

Comment: @iwarv What does Schema contain? why is it stateful? I would expect it to be Database agnostic and the DatabaseConnection would create a Query against the database alone taking the agnostic schema into account.

Comment: @Raildex those are the types of questions that explore the nature of the application and possibilities of XY and detract from the problem statement here, which is how two PIMPL types can cooperate without compromising their public interface.

Answer (score 0):

I was given this solution in another forum.

The "mistake" I made was that the private class was declared in the .cpp file. That means that it's perhaps a little too opaque.
It can work that way, but only as a standalone PIMPL.
As I found out when two PIMPLs need to interact, this becomes a design problem.

The suggestion is to move the declaration of the private class into a separate header.
This header should *not* live among the interfaces but rather among the source files.

```
   root
     ├─── Inc
     │     └── Schema.h
     │         DatabaseConnection.h
     └─── Src
           └── SchemaPrivate.h
               Schema.cpp
               DatabaseConnectionPrivate.h
               DatabaseConnection.cpp
```

For example: the `Schema::Impl` class declaration is moved wholesale into SchemaPrivate.h.
Any definition for this class can still live in file Schema.cpp.

You can then add any getter you need to these private classes.
You make the classes at the interface level (in folder root/inc) friends where needed.

Now you could (example):

```cpp
#include "DatabaseConnection.h"

// NOTE: these two headers come from different dirs
#include "Schema.h"        // root/Inc
#include "SchemaPrivate"   // root/Src

void DatabaseConnection::Impl::createTable(const Schema& schema)
{
    Schema::Impl* pschema = schema.p_;
    assert(pschema != nullptr);

    pschema->getTable(); // solved, we have access to schema's innards
    ...
}
```

If you were to build this as a library using cmake you would perhaps:

```
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Inc
    PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Src
)
```

So client code would inherit the public interface in root/Inc.
But they would not implicitly get access to the private classes.

It's a compromise, but it's thus far the best solution under the circumstance.